# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'astor'

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu-16.04

I have been trying to run the Mask R-CNN demo from matter plot (https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN). It works with tensorflow version 1.13.1 and keras 2.1.0 as suggested by someone here (https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN/issues/1797). I get the error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'astor'
```

The thing is astor 0.8.0 is installed in my virtual env but when trying to import it, it say it does not exist. I have made sure to install it normally as well as sudo. If you think it does exist on $PYTHONPATH, how can I do it. I am out of my depth here, so please be considerate.

EDIT: I am using virtualenv in pyCharm. If I look through my *interpreter paths*, I get

```
file:///home/$SUER/anaconda3/lib/python3.6
file:///home/$USER/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload
file:///home/$USER/project/Mask_RCNN/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages
file:///home/$USER/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages
```

I have replace my actual user name with *$USER* in the above output.

Comment: Check if the `python` is pointing to the virtualenv python executable.

Comment: @bigbounty so i am running the code on pycharm and I have set the interpreter as required. However, if I go to the venv terminal in pycharm and do echo $PYTHONPATH, i get blank

Comment: @bigbounty can you also say which folder/file I have to point to...i.e. what constitutes the virtualenv python executable?

Comment: I suppose your venv and pycharm python are referring to 2 different python executables

Comment: @bigbounty I have added the interepreter paths as listed on the pyCharm...it seems to be including the venv path...look at the edit I made to the post

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @bigbounty, but his questions made me understand a bit more about PYTHONPATH. Maybe something that I already should have known but you make mistakes and learn.

**SOLUTION**: in the venv interpreter paths I added

```
/home/$USER/anaconda3/pkgs/astor-0.8.0-py36_0/lib/python3.6/site-packages
```

and it worked. I do not know why the package was installed in this folder where apparently it was not included.

Answer (score 0):

i solve copyng the astor folder from site-package (in env) to my project folder and set is as source( in pycharm)